# How to apply FrameworkPropertyMetadata.AffectsArrange to a DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf

In a custom control I have a class which derives from DependencyObject and has a dependency property called MaxIdealWidth. I have several custom controls which do some pretty weird measure/arrange, and they all use this property in some way, but not in a binding.

My problem is, when everything is drawn the first time, it works well. However when the MaxIdealWidth is changed by one custom control, none of the others will do measure/arrange. I can understand why this happens, but I need to force all custom controls to measure/arrange at the same time.

### FrameworkPropertyMetadata.AffectsArrange

Looking at the documentation, this looks like a promising way forward, however I have absolutely no idea how to apply it in practice. It doesn't seem to be documented from a point of view of how to use it in my situation. Can someone tell me how to apply AffectsArrange from XAML or code-behind to indicate from a custom control that a dependency property on the DataContext should cause measure/arrange?

Comment: Are all these custom controls children of a common parent control? Then you could probably set FrameworkPropertyMetadata.AffectsParentMeasure/Arrange.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, they are all items in an ItemsControl which is on a parent custom control. How would I link the DependencyProperty to the AffectsParentMeasure flag? (Remember that the DP is not on the parent custom control, it is on a different object)

Comment: Why don't you just show the relevant parts of your code instead of trying to explain your code structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do that by using the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` class instead of the `PropertyMetadata` for the last Parameter of the dependency propery Registration. There you set all the bits you like:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ArrowEndsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("your name",
            typeof(<class>), typeof(<owner class>),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(<initial value>,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
```

Comment: This is the right answer so I marked it, however I never could get it working in the end. For some reason even with AffectsMeasure set updating that field didn't update the layout.